# collapsing sidebar and accordion with small screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to reproduce the effects of this template page https://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_58977/services.html#undefined1

But I don't know how to change the content just like panel with nav tabs. I've find this example on stackoverflow http://www.bootply.com/88026 .

How it is possible to transform this on a accordion only for small screen?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm actually trying to do it by myself here https://jsfiddle.net/v3vjf5n4/1/, but I don't know how to transform the nav-stacked to accordion for small screen

Comment: ahh now i understand what you want to do.. you could build both of them.. one for the big screen and one for small Screens and hide one of them using javascript

Comment: just edited my answer, take a look at it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this using JavaScript.

```
function clickedLink(linkID){
  // ------------------------------------------------------ hide all
  document.getElementById('home').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('link1').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('link2').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('link3').style.display = 'none';
  // ------------------------------------------------------ show active
  document.getElementById(linkID).style.display = '';
}
```

Here is a working solution: http://www.bootply.com/4EsSTTHzGs

// EDIT: 
Now i undersatnd what you want to do :)
You could build both of them and use hidden-xx (xx: xs, sm, md, lg)

Take a look at this: http://www.bootply.com/HIFkqIQgI3

if you don't want to write the same Content twice, you could include the Content with php using something like `<?php include 'folderx/contentx.html'; ?>`

> If this is working for you, mark this Answer as the right Answer.. :)

Comment: HOOOO you are my men !!
Thanks a lot !